# Proxy pass through 2 nginx servers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have some issues with nginx and servers.

Here's my first configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  *.example.com;

    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }
}
```

It then proxy pass to an other nginx server listening on the port 8000 everything matched by the wildcard `*.example.com`.

Then the next server has a few configurations that are automatically generated. Those looks like  this:

```
upstream upstream_project1 {                                                                                                      
    server 172.18.0.5:8069;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  project1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_project_1;
    }
}
```

and

```
upstream upstream_project2 {                                                                                                      
    server 172.18.0.6:8069;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  project2.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_project_2;
    }
}
```

Then the request is proxy passed to the application server running according to the upstream defined in each config.

The problem I have is if I have a few projects and each project have different IPs / hostname. The request seems to only go through the first configuration.

It feels like the first proxy send the request and set the headers properly has my application server react as it's correctly proxied.

The problem is that it proxy the wrong application server.

Also, if I kill the application server, that it matches first it will used a different one as if it was falling back to a "default" server.

Comment: This setup is a bit confusing. What do you mean you have "multiple project1"s? So how many domain names are we talking about and how do you want to distribute them? In your current configuration upstream is simply not needed at all.

Comment: Each project may have multiple upstreams. Here I marked one for simplicity. I meant that I have multiple project say project1.example.com, project2.example.com, project3.example.com etc.. And each project may have multiple upstreams but that's not the problem I have right now. The problem is that the second nginx server serves on the wrong server_name as if it was matching a default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx uses the `Host` header to select an appropriate `server` block, otherwise the default server block (or the first server block if no default is defined) will be used to process the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

By default, `proxy_pass` sets the `Host` header to the value specified in the `proxy_pass` directive (i.e. `127.0.0.1:8000`).

Try adding the following to your reverse proxy configuration:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Comment: That's perfect. That's what I thought.